# How to load different arrays when tapping cells in TableViewController?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

I've been looking for hours and can't seem to find an answer for this. My swift file contains over 20 really long arrays but I'm going to simplify it in this question with a short similar example.

Let's say I have a "Class A" with an array that goes like this:

```
var mainArray = ["One, "Two", "Three"]

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellA = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototype1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cellA.textLabel?.text = mainArray[indexPath.row]
    return cellA
}
```

and then there's "Class B" with multiple arrays, like so:

```
var arrayOne = ["A", "B", "C"]
var arrayTwo = ["D", "E", "F", "G"]
var arrayThree = ["H", "I"]
var itemArray = [String]()

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return itemArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellB = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototype2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cellB.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    return cellB
}
```

What I've been trying to figure out is how to choose a specific array to display.

For example, in this case I would want to tap the cell with the label 'Two' in the main array and segue to the second view controller (Class B) and display four cells labeled:

D

E

F

G

respectively.

If anyone can help me with this I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a property (like below code) in your Class B and before opening the class set that property with a value like 1 or 2 or 3.

```
   public var arrayNumber : Int?
```

Then in your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` based on the value of that property ( `arrayNumber` ) decide to use from one of the `arrayOne` or `arrayTwo` or `arrayThree`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

if arrayNumber == 1
    return arrayOne.count
else if arrayNumber == 2
    return arrayTwo.count
else 
    return arrayThree.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellB = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototype2", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if arrayNumber == 1
        cellB.textLabel?.text = arrayOne[indexPath.row]
    else if arrayNumber == 2
        cellB.textLabel?.text = arrayTwo[indexPath.row]
    else 
       cellB.textLabel?.text = arrayThree[indexPath.row]    

return cellB
}
```

if you have different design for each array, you should separate `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` too.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable as follows

```
public var arrayChoice : Int?
```

This variable will be controlling which array to load in your tableview

Then in the tableview delegate methods do something as follows

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    switch (arrayChoice){
    case 1:
        //return no of items in array 1
    case 2:
        //return no of items in array 2
    default:
        p//return no of items in default condition
    } 
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
switch (arrayChoice){
    case 1:
        let cellA = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cellA.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    return cellA
    case 2:
let cellB = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cellB.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    return cellB

    default:
        let cellDefault = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cellDefault.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    return cellDefault
    }
}
```

This is just to give you an idea on how to tackle your situation. Before loading the table just make sure that you have made some selection which cell to be loaded.

Hope this helps....